# Spreadsheet not found error - Umlaut in file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, gspread

I am trying to open several files using open from gspread. However, I get a spreadsheet not found error when the files have characters in their names that have umlauts (i.e. Sprüngli). I haven't been able to find anything related to this in the gspread or Google Drive API docs. Is there a way to work around this without changing the names of the files?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [SO]! When I tried to [reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/pastor-robert/0e77d10639f1835c0ccc6bf244c5e932), it worked perfectly for me. Could you create and test a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you entering the umlaut characters into the names you are trying to open? Or are you trying to enter non-diacritical characters in their place (e.g., `Sprungli` for `Sprüngli`)? If the latter, these will never match. We don't currently have enough information to answer much beyond this.

Comment: @ErikTyler I am not switching the names.
I will try to create a reproducible example.

Comment: So I did some further testing: I am running the gspread open command for all the values in a list. And it seems the name gets messed up while doing so, the umlaut somehow gets separated from the letter and they turn into two separate characters.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out my solution. The umlauts were somehow getting separated from the letters as I was iterating through a list of the filenames and I solved it with unicodedata.normalize.

```
from unicodedata import name, normalize
[normalize('NFC', s) for s in filenames]
```